# XPath expression to get node based on attribute value

Tags: xml, bash, shell, xpath, xmllint

I have the following input xml file:

```
<rootnode>
 <section id="1" status="fail">
  <outer status="fail">
   <inner status="fail"/>
   <inner status="pass"/>
  </outer>
  <outer status="pass">
   <inner status="pass"/>
  </outer>
  <outer status="pass"/>
  <outer status="fail"/>
 </section>
 <section id="2" status="fail">
  <outer status="fail">
   <inner status="pass"/>
   <inner status="fail"/>
   <inner status="inc"/>
  </outer>
 </section>
</rootnode>
```

I want to filter out all non-fail status nodes so that the result looks like this:

```
<rootnode>
 <section id="1" status="fail">
  <outer status="fail">
   <inner status="fail"/>
  </outer>
  <outer status="fail"/>
 </section>
 <section id="2" status="fail">
  <outer status="fail">
   <inner status="fail"/>
  </outer>
 </section>
</rootnode>
```

The `<rootnode>` must not necessarily be included in the result. I have tried to use `xmllint` with an xpath expression. I can extract specific nodes with

```
xmllint --xpath "//inner" input.xml
xmllint --xpath "//@status" input.xml
```

but they only either return the nodes without regard to the value of `status` or the only return the attribute without the surrounding nodes.

Is there a way to do this with an xpath expression? If not, a *simple* solution which incorporates other bash tools is fine, too.

Comment: You need an xslt not xpath, you know that when xpath returns a node with status = 'fail' that has an inner element like inner status='pass' you will get that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @svasa said in a comment, you should use XSLT. You can easily process the XSLT in bash with [xsltproc](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc.html),  [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) (using `tr` command), [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) (java on the [command line](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/using-xsl/commandline.html)), etc.

Here's an example using xsltproc:

```
$ xsltproc so.xsl so.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rootnode>
  <section id="1" status="fail">
    <outer status="fail">
      <inner status="fail"/>
    </outer>
    <outer status="fail"/>
  </section>
  <section id="2" status="fail">
    <outer status="fail">
      <inner status="fail"/>
    </outer>
  </section>
</rootnode>
```

**XML Input** (so.xml)

```
<rootnode>
    <section id="1" status="fail">
        <outer status="fail">
            <inner status="fail"/>
            <inner status="pass"/>
        </outer>
        <outer status="pass">
            <inner status="pass"/>
        </outer>
        <outer status="pass"/>
        <outer status="fail"/>
    </section>
    <section id="2" status="fail">
        <outer status="fail">
            <inner status="pass"/>
            <inner status="fail"/>
            <inner status="inc"/>
        </outer>
    </section>
</rootnode>
```

**XSLT 1.0** (so.xsl)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[@status[not(normalize-space()='fail')]]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

> I have a small follow-up question, if you don't mind. When the
>   input.xml file does not contain any status=fail nodes, then the output
>   is just two lines: `<?xml version="1.0"?>` and `<rootnode/>`. Is it
>   possible two suppress the output entirely in this case? It is not
>   really a problem, I know how to work around it in bash. I am just
>   interested if there is a clean solution via xslt.

What you could do is omit the XML declaration (`omit-xml-declaration="yes"` in `xsl:output`) and check to see if there are any elements with `status="fail"`. I'd use a key (`xsl:key`) for this...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes">
    <!--If you need to output the declaration when there
    are elements with status="fail", it might be best to post process files that
    only contain the xml declaration.-->
  </xsl:output>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!--Key of all elements with status="fail".-->  
  <xsl:key name="fails" match="*[@status='fail']" use="@status"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*[not(key('fails','fail'))]">
    <!--If there aren't any elements with status="fail", don't process
    anything else.-->
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[@status[not(normalize-space()='fail')]]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I have a small follow-up question, if you don't mind. When the input.xml file does not contain any `status=fail` nodes, then the output is just two lines: `<?xml version="1.0"?>` and `<rootnode/>`. Is it possible two suppress the output entirely in this case? It is not really a problem, I know how to work around it in bash. I am just interested if there is a clean solution via xslt.

Comment: Thanks. Much appreciated.